# Further clarification of _property after readonly attribute?

Tags: objective-c, properties, readonly, ivars

When setting the readonly attribute in the interface section this 'disables' the setter method for the property. I need some clarification with:

1. What is the point of the readonly property if we can just set it using _propertyName?
2. When to use _propertyName if our property is readwrite?
3. Also I understand we use setter methods for a degree of abstraction, rather than just assigning the value using _propertyName. Is there any other reason NOT to use _propertyName?

Here is some example code below. Thankyou.

Interface Section

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *licensePlate;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *bodyColor;
```

Implmentation Section

```
-(id) initWithCarFeatures {
    self = [super init]
    if (self) {
        _licensePlate = @"XSHJDS8687";
        _bodyColor = @"blueColor";
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The point is "encapsulation". No other files will be able to directly set the property. The property can be set only from the given file, for example, using `init`, or using a specialized method.
2. Most people will tell you that you should use `_property` directly only in `init` method, `dealloc` (if you are not using ARC) and of course, if you are implementing your own setter and getter. Even if the property is declared as `readonly`, usually you declare it `readwrite` in class extension. Therefore, it will stay `readonly` for other files but it will be `readwrite` for the implementation file (class) that declares it.
3. Many reasons, for example "inheritance" - setters can be overridden. For `copy` properties, the copying is handled by the setter. With MRC (not ARC), setters are even more important (they handle retains and releases).

Comment: Sulthan, just one thing, when you mentioned "can only be set from a given file" does that mean you can only do _propertyName in the implmentation file in the class the readonly was declared? ty

Comment: @CescSergey No, this is a more complicated question. `_propertyName` is an "ivar" (instance variable). You can actually declare it in the `@interface` to be completely public. However, usually when you are using `ivar` to back up a property, you make it private (synthesizing makes it private). That means only the class can access it. The declaration of property doesn't limit the access to the ivar by any way.

Comment: Do the default implementations of getters and/or setters do anything else other than just get or set the underlying variable? In other words, is code generated inside those methods automatically to do any kind of memory management? If I create my own setter, for example, do I need to include any memory management code in it?

Comment: @David Of course. The magic inside is pretty complicated. I would recommend you to raise a separate question. For example, if the property is declared as `atomic`, there will be some synchronization mechanism. I am not sure what do you mean my memory management in this case, however the method is very different with MRC and with ARC.

Comment: I meant that if I implement my own getter/setter, am I then responsible for ensuring that all the property attributes are addressed by my implementation. So if I declare a property as atomic, then I need to make sure I implement atomic behavior explicitly --- the compiler is not inserting code "around" my getter/setter to support those attributes.

Comment: sultan, its been a while and i forgot. Why do we have to go _propertyName in an init method again? ty